# Not receiving remote control events

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I am attempting to use the lock screen/now playing controls for my app but am not receiving any events. The documentation makes it seem pretty straight forward so I was a bit a surprised when I didn't get any results. My app needs to receive the remote control events for purposes outside of playing audio on the device. I tried to test this by just having it print out some confirmation with NSLog. Do I need to be using an audio or media framework that wasn't mentioned in the documentation? I am not receiving any warnings or errors so I don't think there should be any issues with that... Any insight concerning why the remote control events aren't registering would be greatly appreciated

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Register for lock screen controls
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    //Unregister lock screen controls
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}

//Lock screen controls
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"RECEIVED");
    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (event.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                NSLog(@"RECEIVED");
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
                NSLog(@"RECEIVED");
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                NSLog(@"RECEIVED");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Jojas mentioned you need to make sure that you have an active audio session. Look at [AVAudioSession setActive:withFlags:error:].

Comment: Hmm ok. I was wondering if the lack of an audio session was part of the problem.

Comment: This was the issue. My app does not play audio itself, but rather communicates with another device playing audio. I added the audio session but it would only receive remote events if the app had been the last to play some audio. I will be posting a new question about how to work around this but I wanted to thank you!

Comment: @Squatch, Did you end up posting another question?

Comment: @Moshe - I did. Never got an answer though! The feature wasn't vital for the project, so it ultimately did not get implemented. At this time, I do not have a clean solution. Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10885047/1245406

Answer (score 1):

Did you already ensure that your application every state to setup `ReceivingRemoteControlEvents` is fine?

You should look out for necessary protocol via [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in your AppDelegate.
It seem that you need to implement in `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

However, there are Apple's document about [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3). I think it will help you handle the application state with your purpose.

Hope it helps you !

Comment: I believe you're right. The code posted was all in my view controller and I didn't set these active state methods in my delegate. I will try your suggestion and report back.

Comment: It turns out I had those methods implemented by the default AppDelegate. The problem was with my lack of an audio session. Thanks you for your help though. The documentation you linked helped a great deal when trying to understand exactly what was going on.

Comment: I'm glad to help you. feel free to ask.